# How to draw "multidimensional" graphs in Matlab. (i.e. each dot represents a confusion 2x2 matrix)

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, matlab-figure

I run experiments and analyze the data with Matlab.
currently, I have results of success rates arranged by sessions.
(one dot for each session of a few hundreds of trials).

Since each dot represents a whole session, a lot of information is missing in such a graph. 
It **is** important for more data to be on the same graph (committee requirements).
Therefore I would like to attach to each point in the graph a small 2x2 table which shows the 'true positive' 'false positive','true negative','false negative'.
I can have this data, saved as an array of 2x2 matrices, or as an array of structs. (where each point in the graph, i.e. each session of few hundred trials, has its own matrix or struct).
But I have no idea whatsoever how to attach these confusion matrices to the success-rate-denoting points of the graph.
I attach a figure of what I have in mind.
And a figure that shows what is a confusion matrix.

If anyone knows how to create this "multidimensional" graphs in Matlab, and can give here an example or even just a tip, I will be grateful.

[image: What I have in mind]
[image: Confusuin Matrix explained]

Comment: How about an [`area`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html) plot? Then you would just need to put the values for 'true positive', 'false positive','true negative','false negative' in a 4 by `number_of_sessions` array.

Comment: Of those 4 values, 2 are redundant. Why not plot just two lines, alpha and beta?

Comment: Please add a minimum set of sample data.